# How to calculate full width half max of this curve

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the full width half max of this function and I keep receiving non-sense answers. The function is $F(ω)=A_0 (\frac{\frac{1}{τ}}{(\frac{1}{τ^2})+(ω_0 - ω)^2})$ and I then have calculated $F(ω_{1/2}) = \frac{A_0 τ}{2} = A_0 (\frac{\frac{1}{τ}}{(\frac{1}{τ^2})+(ω_0 - ω_{1/2})^2})$ to be $ω_{1/2} = ω_0 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}τ}$ which is non-sense because the units don't make sense.

Comment: Why don't the units make sense? If we can add $\tau^{-2}$ and $(\omega_0 - \omega)^2$, they seem to have the same units, hence it should also be possible to add $\omega_0$ and $\tau^{-1}$.

Comment: I think $\omega_{1/2}$ would be $\omega_0\pm \frac{1}{r}$.

Comment: @AshishGaurav Yeah, I reworked it and got what you got.